# How to add load more records with Spinner in FlatList react-native (means -10 - 10 records) manually! not from using server side

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

Hi I am developing sample application based on FlatList this is my code here. Actually i showed entire records like i have 50 records to my account . But now i am displaying entire 50 records. Bur i need show 10 after adding to 10 records. But i don't know adding to FlatList.

Here this is my code:

```
<FlatList
                    data={this.state.profiles}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderCard(item, index)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Divider style={{ marginTop: 5, marginLeft: width * 0.2 + 20 }} parentStyle={{ backgroundColor: globalStyles.BG_COLOR, alignItems: 'baseline' }} />}
                />


renderCard (profile, index) {
    console.log('rendercard', profile);
    //
    return (
        <View key={profile.id}>
            <ProfileCard
                profile={profile}
                style={styles.card}
                onPress={() => this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation.navigate('Profile', { profile: this.state.profile, id: profile.id })}
                // onPress={() => alert('PROFILE')}
                onAddClick={() => this.setState({ connectionPageVisible: true, cardProfile: profile })}
                connectedIds={(this.props.screenProps && this.props.screenProps.connectedIds) || this.props.connectedIds}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Please show me load more records with Activity Indicator.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ideally, if you're getting the profiles from some  `api`, then you need to add a limit to the `api` to return 10 results, and a url object for the next 10 elements and so on, like what `SoundCloud` does

Comment: thanks for your response! from service side they didn't give any size limit

Answer (score 17):

If I have understood your problem properly, then you are looking for `infinite scrolling` in `Flatlist`. You can achieve this with the help of `onEndReached` and `onEndThreshold` attributes.

Consider the following prototype

Assuming you are storing records into `this.state.profiles`.

**Pulling new records from the server**

Setting initial page number in the constructor

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = { page: 0}
}
```

Fetching new records

```
fetchRecords = (page) => {
    // following API will changed based on your requirement
    fetch(`${API}/${page}/...`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
       this.setState({
           profiles: [...this.state.profiles, ...response.data] // assuming response.data is an array and holds new records
       });
    });
}
```

to handle scroll

```
onScrollHandler = () => {
     this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1
     }, () => {
        this.fetchRecords(this.state.page);
     });
}
```

Render function

```
render() {
    return(
        ...
        <FlatList
           data={this.state.profiles}
           renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderCard(item, index)}
           keyExtractor={item => item.id}
           ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Divider style={{ marginTop: 5, marginLeft: width * 0.2 + 20 }} parentStyle={{ backgroundColor: globalStyles.BG_COLOR, alignItems: 'baseline' }} />}
           onEndReached={this.onScrollHandler}
           onEndThreshold={0}
        />
        ...
    );
}
```

**Local updates**

If you have already pulled all the data, but want to show only `10` at a time, then all you need to do is change the `fetchRecords`

```
fetchRecords = (page) => {
  // assuming this.state.records hold all the records
  const newRecords = []
  for(var i = page * 10, il = i + 10; i < il && i < this.state.records.length; i++){
      newRecords.push(this.state.records[i]);
  }
  this.setState({
    profiles: [...this.state.profiles, ...newRecords]
  });
}
```

Above approach will show `Activity Indicator` while pulling records.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am getting all records from api. and in my api i didn't have any page size attribute or keyword

Comment: Ok, for this I have provided `Local updates`, where it is assumed that all the data is pulled at first, then when user reach to end of the list, it will populate data from the local state. Take a look at `Local updates` part.

Comment: BTW, `page` is mentained locally to indicate pegination only. I just wanted to make it extendable, so that if there is any change in the API, all u need to do is change the `fetchRecords` method.

Comment: I mean, now you are populating data from local, if there is any change in future to populate data from backend then you just need to change fetch method. I think `Local updates` section should solve your issue.

Comment: But my api  have not size option

Comment: Yes, right now there is no support in your API, so your issue can be solved using `Local updates` section mentioned in my answer.

Comment: thanks but on updating state my flat list goes to start, means if i have 10 item at first the i got next 10 and i append the new array to the previous 10 item, so, state is updated and my component is rerendered and flatllist scroll to first item